# Is train_test_split necessary for binary classification? And why are there 4 outcomes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

Why are there 4 outcomes to train_test_split in sklearn? Why is there y_test, if the testing data has no y_data?

Comment: If you have both training and testing data available, then I'm confused why you need to use `train_test_split`.  `train_test_split` is to take a data matrix and to purposefully split them into a training and test set.  If you have them already available, there's no need to do this?

Comment: What I'm saying is train_test_split has an outcome of x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, whilst I only have my training and testing data. What is the need of the 4 outcomes?

Comment: My point is that you don't even need to use it, hence you don't need the four outcomes.  The four outcomes are when you **don't already have your data split into training and test**.  It's simply one data matrix and you **want** to obtain training and test from it.  Because that job is already done for you, you don't even need to use it.

Comment: Okay, so why does train_test_split have 4 outcomes, rather than simply splitting into 2?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my answer.  You provide `train_test_split` with **one** data matrix and **one** vector of labels.  This data matrix and vector of labels is **not already split into training and test**.  The job **is to do so**.  So right now, you have just two things - the data matrix and the vector of labels.  We get four **because we split the data matrix into a training and test set**.  Therefore, we get a split data matrix and vector of labels as a training set, and the same for the test (hence 2 + 2 = 4). I really don't know how else to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get 4 outcomes is because you get: train_features, test_features, train_labels and test_labels (`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`). So it not just splits the dataset into train and test set, but also the labels. (so 2 + 2 = 4 outcomes).

Comment: As the testing data contains no current binary labels, would that mean that y_test is null?

Comment: How are you training (and testing) if you don't have labels? train_test_split is only useful if you have labels. You can classify unlabeled data, but how do you then test the performance of the classification (the thing you use train_test_split for)?

Comment: My mistake was confusing validation sets and testing sets.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), you can see that the first parameter is 
`*arrays`, which means you can put as many arrays as you want there. Now, what does it returns?

```
Returns:    splitting : list, length=2 * len(arrays)
```

Which means it returns twice the amount of arrays passed in the train_test_split function.

So, if you already have a training and a testing set, it only makes sense to split the training set, so you can have a validation set to check the model performance.

Eg.:

```
train_data, validation_data, train_label, validation_label= train_test_split(original_train_data, original_train_label)
```

Note that you also must split the labels in the case you have the data and the label in separated vectors.

Answer (score 0):

because you have split your original data into train and test parts. so there would be four outcomes.

1 (X_train, Y_train) where X_train are the training points while Y_train are their respective class labels. Now this is your training data which will be used to train your model with any classical models like K-NN, logistic regression , Decision Tress.

2 (X_test,Y_test) where X_test represents your test data point and y_train are your respective class labels for these test points.Now once you  have trained your model and calculated your training error/accuracy, then you can use these points to see whether the trained model predicts the data correctly or not.The lower the difference between your training and test error the better it is.

That is why you get 4 outcomes with pairs of 2 each.

Hope this helps.